# What is the motivation for prefers-reduced-transparency media query parameter

Tags: css, media-queries, accessibility, w3c

I was checking existing media-query parameters on MDN ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Media_features))

I saw `prefers-reduced-transparency` parameter:

> The user prefers reduced transparency *(Added in Media Queries Level 5)*

I see the point for prefered themes (dark/light) or reduced animations, but I don't understand the need behind this rule.
I can't find any W3C exchanges that would explain why they added this to MQ5.

Does someone has infos on this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [issue](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/443) at [csswg-drafts](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts), there's a reference to a [discussion thread](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2016Feb/0037.html) that has the following clue:

> `prefers-reduced-transparency`
>
> Allows certain translucent views to switch to an opaque rendering.
>
> (…­) This increases readability for certain individuals with vision impairments.

So the underlying need for this rule would be aiding vision impairment among users. I also would like to see some more documentation on this feature.

Comment: Thanks ! Not sure what kind of impairments they talk about. I have a feeling that this might be the same need behind `prefers-contrast: high`

Comment: It's a separate concern to `prefers-contrast: high`. I've given another answer with an overview of how it relates to cognitive impairments.

Answer (score 3):

Many groups of people may find it easier to understand text (and UI controls), or focus on activities, if they are presented with a plain, opaque background.

As Cody says in their answer, it can increase readability for users with **visual** impairments. For example:

- A person with astigmatism may find it easier to read text on a plain background. (I do, and I frequently misplace my spectacles.)

It also benefits users with various **cognitive** impairments too. Background images, textures, gradients, or other patterns can:

- Make shape recognition more difficult, e.g. for people with dyslexia or visual-spatial processing impairments.
- Appear too "loud" or intense for people with autism-spectrum cognitive impairments.
- Appear too "busy" for people with distractability or working-memory impairments.
- Increase the cognitive effort required when a user is tired, or is experiencing a headache.

(I'm not an expert on cognitive impairments, so this simplistic overview is the best I can give just now. There are many more types and degrees of cognitive impairments.)

Note that `prefers-reduced-transparency` and `prefers-contrast` are separate concerns. The CSS-WG tracking issue for this ([Media Feature: "increase contrast" and/or "reduce transparency" user settings](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/443#issuecomment-245147480)) has a useful comment:

> Low vision disabilities are too diverse to make sweeping generalizations like, "People who what higher contrast text also want zero transparency"